# Combining hard coded values with values from models in select list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a select list that I want to populate with some hard coded values along with some values from AR. For example, I have a list for the user to select payment options for a transaction.

- Credit Card
- Cash
- Gift Certificate

Easy enough...

```
<%= select_tag :paying_with, options_for_select([["Credit card", "credit_card"], ["Cash", "cash"], ["Gift Certificate", "gift_certificate"]] %>
```

Now I want to remove the generic "Credit Card" option and include each credit card the user has on file (e.g. each `PaymentMethod` model belonging to the `User`)

- Your MasterCard ending in 1234
- Your AmEx ending in 4321
- Cash
- Gift Certificate

I know how to do both individually but I can't seem to figure out how to blend them. Note that I am using a `select_tag` instead of the `FormHelper.select` because this doesn't necessarily correspond to a property on a model.

Comment: How about creating an array and then passing that array in options_for_select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a combination of Nikita's comment and the good old fashion `<<` operator. I originally wanted to keep the query in the view but it was getting too complex there.

```
    @payment_options = []
    @payment_options << ["No charge", "no_charge"]
    @payment_options += PaymentMethod.where(...).map { |p| [p.name, p.id] }.to_a
    @payment_options << ["Cash", "cash"]
    @payment_options << ["Gift Certificate", "gift_certificate"]
```

...and in the view...

```
<%= select_tag :paying_with, options_for_select(@payment_options, enrollment.paying_with || "no_charge") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@options = @user.credit_cards.map{ |c| ["Your #{c.card_name} ending in #{c.card_last_four_digits", c]}.insert(["Cash", "cash"]).insert(["Gift Certificate", "gift_certificate"])
```

That will give you an array to pass to options_for_select.  I'm guessing on some variable names, since you didn't post the relevant code.